# Where can I find official Land Use/Land Cover GIS data for Ecuador?

Tags: land-cover, land-use, data, ecuador

Right now I'm specifically looking for Land Use/Land Cover data but things like roads and soils would be handy in the future as well. In the U.S. my source for nationwide LULC data would be the Multi-Resolution Land Characteristics (MRLC) Consortium but I don't know the equivalent group/agency in Ecuador, if there is one.

I do have some LULC data for Ecuador and it is pretty detailed, so I think that there **is** official LULC data for the country but I need to be able to cite my sources. Also, the data I have (from 2008) is in vector format but it was obviously converted from raster, so it would be great if I could get a hold of the original, untouched raster and its metadata. Basically, I'm trying to identify the provenance of the data I do have, and find more of it (for different years) if it exists.

Comment: what resolution/level of detail do you need ?

Comment: The resolution of the data I do have is 30 meters, so 30m. Basically I'm looking to track down the provenance of the data I have and find more like it for different time periods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find Ecuadoran LULC data on a couple of Ecuadoran government servers, as well as quite a few other layers, if anyone needs them in the future. I was not able to find all the older LULC data I was looking for. Here's what I found. If, like me, you don't speak Spanish, Google Translate is a big help navigating these sites:

- [El Sistema Nacional de Información (SNI)](http://sni.gob.ec/coberturas), the National Information System, has soils data, land use/land cover, rivers, and quite a few other layers.
- [Ministerio de Agricultura, Ganadería, Acuacultura y Pesca (MAGAP)](http://geoportal.magap.gob.ec/inventario.html), the Ministry of Agriculture, Livestock, Aquaculture and Fisheries. This data overlaps a bit with the data available from SNI, but offers several layers that SNI doesn't. They also offer some [datasets by province](http://geoportal.magap.gob.ec/inventarioprov.html) if what you're looking for isn't covered in the nationwide datasets.